Induction argument to prove analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ to $\mathbb C$ $\setminus\{1\}$
This exercise computes an alternative proof of the following theorem: $\zeta(s)$ has an analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$, with a pole with residue 1 at $s = 1$. Equivalently, if $G(s) := (s-1)(\zeta(s)-1)$, then $G(s)$ has an analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$ and $G(1) = 1$.
a) For $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\text{Re} \, s > 1$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, define
$$
F_k(s) := \int_1^\infty (x - \lfloor x \rfloor)^k x^{-s} \, dx.
$$
Prove that $F_0(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}$ and
$$
F_k(s) = \frac{1}{k+1} \left( \zeta(s+k) - 1 + (s+k)F_{k+1}(s) \right).
$$
b) Let $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Prove that for $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\text{Re} \, s > 1$, we have
$$
G(s) = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{r} \frac{(s-1)s(s+1)\cdots(s+k-2)(s+k)G(s+k)}{(k+1)!} - \frac{(s-1)s(s+1)\cdots(s+r)}{(r+1)!}F_{r+1}(s).
$$
c) Prove by induction on $r$ that for every $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, the function $G(s)$ has an analytic continuation to $U_r := \{s \in \mathbb{C} : \text{Re} \, s > r\}$, and then deduce that $G(s)$ has an analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$. Show also that $G(1) = 1$ and $G(0) = \frac{1}{2}$, hence $\zeta(0) = -\frac{1}{2}$.
I have already successfully proven $a$ and $b$, I am stuck at part $c$.  For the base step of the induction $r=0$ I have:
From part $b$ for $r=0$ we know that $G(s)=1-s(s-1)F_1(s)$. Here the domain is the $s$ for which Re$ s >1 $, since that is where $\zeta (s)$ is initially defined. But I don't know how to argue that $G(s)$ has an analytic continuation to Re$ s >0 $.
reference lecture notes: https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertsejh/ant20-4.pdf
Edit: Assuming that the based step is true by the well-known proof,as in the notes, since the problem does not really say if that is not supposed to be considered true already. I think the focus of the problem is on the extension from Re$(s)>0$ to $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$ via this recursive method. I'll assume it is true, how would you prove the inductive step?
Assume $G(s)$ is analytic on $U_r$, I want to prove that it is also analytic on $U_{r+1}$. Looking at the recursive formula how can I prove that $G(s+k)$ and $F_{r+1}(s)$ are analytic on $U_{r+1}$ ?Perhaps the following theorem helps



I'm not quite sure what the intended proof is. The shape of the question suggests to me that there is an intended obvious continuation of $F_r$ to $\mathrm{Re} s > -r + 1$. If this were true, then a straightforward induction would work. But actually any continuation of $F_r$ immediately gives a continuation of $\zeta(s)$ already, without passing through $G$. Repeatedly integrating by parts works and is essentially equivalent to the Euler-Maclaurin method of continuing $\zeta(s)$. I would guess that I'm missing something obvious.

@davidlowryduda I applied theorem 0.6.25 to F_r+1 to prove it is analytic and G(s+k) for k from 1 to r are analytic on U_{r+1}, that should give me the inductive step. that G(s ) is analytic from the formual on (b) It would be interesting to see why you don't need to pass through G though
